# getting y position from canvas is wrong

Tags: html, arrays, canvas, coordinates

Sometimes the y-coordinates is greater than height of imagedata. can anybody help me to find my mistake!
Width is 320 px, height is 240px.
Here is my code:

```
function countPixels(context) {
    var nAlive = 0,
        all = [];
    var w = canvas.width;
    var p = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
    for (var y = 0, i = 0; y < canvas.height; y++)
        for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++, i += 4) {
            if (p[i] == 255 || p[i + 1] == 255 || p[i + 2] == 255) //Not black
            {
                nAlive++;
                var xc = i % w;
                var yc = parseInt(i / w, 10);
                var pos = {};
                pos.x = xc;
                pos.y = yc;
                all.push(pos);
            }
        }
    var percent = ((canvas.width * canvas.height) / 100) * nAlive;
    console.log("Count: " + nAlive + ",percent: " + percent + ",all: " + JSON.stringify(all));
    // $("#notifies").append("Count: "+nAlive+",percent: "+ percent+",all: "+JSON.stringify(all));
    return {
        percentage: parseFloat(percent),
        positions: all
    };
}
```

Here is the function call:

```
var tmp = countPixels(ctx2);
ctx2.strokeStyle = "blue";
$.each(tmp.positions, function(i, value) {
    // if (ctx2.isPointInPath(value.x, value.y))
    $('div').eq(0).append("i: " + i + " " + value.x + ", " + +value.y + '</br>');
    ctx2.rect(value.x, value.y, 5, 5);
});
ctx2.stroke();
```

Comment: Why are you not simply using `x` and `y` instead of calculating `i % w` and `i / w`? What am I missing?

Comment: @MrLister: Thanks, so simple, oh my good, the problem is sitting in front of monitor.

Comment: OK, in that case the problem was that `i` is four times as large as you thought, counting the individual colour channels rather than pixels. ;)